# querySelectorAll outputs an empty array

Tags: javascript, html

It is necessary to find in the block with the "carousel" class all the blocks with the "block3card" class. There are no errors in the console

```js
var carouselblock = new Array();
carouselblock = document.querySelectorAll(".block3card");
console.log(carouselblock)
```

```html
<div id="carousel">
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="block3card">
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <div class="block3card">
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <div class="block3card">
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <div class="block3card">
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <div class="block3card">
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you calling your script in the `<head>` or in the `<body>` (after the `div#carousel` element)? You may need to wait until `DOMContentLoaded` is fired.

Comment: I connected the script in the head tag

Comment: @boulder - Your best bet here in 2023 is to add `type="module"` to that `script` tag, so the file is used as a module, not a script. One of the several reasons that's better is that execution of modules is automatically deferred until the DOM has been loaded. (Also: top-level declarations are no longer globals, strict mode is automatic, and other good stuff.) But you have other options, see [the linked question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element).

Comment: Place the script just prior to the closing `body` tag. Currently your JS is running before the DOM is loaded so no elements are found.